# Setting up in-memory H2 database without Spring Boot

Tags: spring, h2, in-memory-database

I am working on a spring 5 (Not Sprig Boot) project. I need to test my application with in-memory H2 database. I am using Spring with Java Config on maven build tool. Is there any way I can configure in-memory H2 DB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the `DataSource` bean using the [`EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/embedded/EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder.html) as follows:

```java
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource(
        @Value("${datasource.dbname}") String dbname,
        @Value("${datasource.script}") String script) {

    return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
            .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
            .setName(dbname)
            .addScript(script)
            .build();
}
```

application.properties

```ini
datasource.dbname=users
datasource.script=classpath:resources/users.sql
```

Also you can register `h2-console` servlet in the application configuration class as follows:

```java
@Configuration
public class WebAppConfig implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) {
        . . .

        servletContext
                .addServlet("H2Console", WebServlet.class)
                .addMapping("/console/*");

        . . .
    }
}
```

Then you can open `http://localhost:8080/console` and connect to the `jdbc:h2:mem:users` database as follows:

[image: login.jsp]

---

<sup>See also [How to enable h2-console in spring-webmvc without spring-boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64488131/8280225)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Usually I use this in my `@Config` class:

```
@Bean
public DataSource h2TestDataSource(){
   return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2).build();
}
```

So I use Spring Embedded DB in my spring projects (I don't use spring boot)

I hope it's useful.