# How to mock the dtabase in J2EE for junit without spring boot

Tags: java, servlets, junit, mockito, h2

I am working on a legacy project which is build on purely Java/J2EE servlets. No spring and other frameworks. It is built on ant.
Now I want to integrate junit with my project, I am able to integrate but I want to mock the DB and run the test cases in the mocked DB connection.
I think in spring boot we can easily do that with H2 database. But only challenge I am facing is we are not using spring boot.
I am able to mock the functions and run the test cases but what I need is to mock the full database and run the test classes on my mocked database.
Any leads how I can achieve this or it is feasible or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sub>You can run `h2 database` in pure `java` since it is written in it. See [H2 Documentation](https://h2database.com/javadoc/index.html).</sub>

---

#### Start `h2 database` server in pure java and run `sql` script

1. To start a *tcp-server* you can use a [`Server`](https://h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/tools/Server.html#createTcpServer_String...) tool:

   ```java
   Server server = Server.createTcpServer();
   server.start();
   ```

   To to start also a *web-server* (with `h2-console`) you can add:

   ```java
   Server server = Server.createWebServer();
   server.start();
   ```
2. To open [`JdbcConnection`](https://h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/jdbc/JdbcConnection.html) and [`RunScript`](https://h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/tools/RunScript.html) you can write something like this:

   ```java
   private void createTables(String url, String username,
                             String password, File script)
           throws SQLException, IOException {

       Properties info = new Properties();
       info.put("user", username);
       info.put("password", password);

       JdbcConnection connection = new JdbcConnection(url, info);
       InputStreamReader reader =
               new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(script));

       RunScript.execute(connection, reader);

       reader.close();
       connection.close();
   }
   ```

---

See also:

- [How to enable h2-console in spring-webmvc without spring-boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64489885/8280225)
- [Setting up in-memory H2 database without Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64491044/8280225)
- [Executing script file in h2 database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10675768/8280225)